# jquery removeClass in current row

Tags: jquery

I have edit button at the last cell of the table. when I click it I am validating inputs if something goes wrong I am adding error class to necessary inputs. when the user will correct mistakes and push edit button again I want to remove error class of current row. but not from all row. How to do it?

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the row/table? My first instinct is to use `.closest()` and get the `<tr>` and then go back down the tree and find input elements from within, but without seeing the code I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the click handler:

```
$(this).closest('tr').removeClass('errorClass');
```

Or if it was from the 'input' elements:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(':input').removeClass('errorClass');
```

Comment: your code did it:-)   $(con).closest('tr').find('.input-validation-error').removeClass('input-validation-error');

Answer (score 1):

Your edit button click handler might look like this:

```
$("selector_for_table tr input[name=edit]").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if (everythingIsValid()) {
        row.removeClass('invalid');
    }
    else {
        row.addClass('invalid');
   }
});
```

That uses [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the first parent element of the clicked button that's a `tr`.

...although you might look at [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for this if you're using an up-to-date jQuery:

```
$("selector_for_table").delegate('input[name=edit]', 'click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if (everythingIsValid()) {
        row.removeClass('invalid');
    }
    else {
        row.addClass('invalid');
   }
});
```

...if the rows are dynamic (e.g., if you add or remove them). `delegate` just sets a handler on the parent element, and then watches for the event to bubble. If it sees the event, and the source element of the event matches the given selector, it fires the handler.

Comment: `.closest('row')` should be `.closest('tr')`, `removeClassName/addClassname` should be `removeClass/addClass`. ;o)

Comment: @patrick: Thanks. What I get for not reading things over. :-)

Comment: @AEMLoviji: Absolutely. @T.J.: Not a problem. Mainly wanted to be sure OP knew. :o)